# Inserting current date time in oracle apex (v20) Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, oracle, oracle-apex, cx-oracle

I am using cx_Oracle in Python to update a timestamp column in an Apex table.

Here is what I have done:

```
  sql1 = ('SELECT * from ab.TEMPTABLE');
  sql2 = ('UPDATE AB.CTIMEUPDATED SET TSTAMP = SYSTIMESTAMP')
    try:
        connection=self.get_connection()
        with connection.cursor() as cursor:
             cursor.execute(sql2)
             cursor.execute(sql1)
```

This doesn't updates the value in `CTIMEUPDATED` table , however if

I run the same command in SQL command browser outside of Python, it works just fine.

I have also tried other options like this

```
d=datetime.datetime.now()
dtime=d.strftime("YYYY/MM/DD HH:mm:ss (%Y/%m/%d %H:%M:%S)")
cursor.prepare( "INSERT INTO AB.CTIMEUPDATED(Tstamp) VALUES(TO_DATE(:TS))" )
cursor.setinputsizes(TS=cx_Oracle.TIMESTAMP)
cursor.execute(None, {'TS':dtime})
```

or

```
cursor.execute("INSERT INTO AB.CTIMEUPDATED(Tstamp) VALUES(TO_DATE(:TS, 'yyyy/mm/dd hh24:mi:ss'))", {'TS': dtime})
```

Nothing works and there is no error as well.

`CTIMEUPDATED` table has a column `TSTAMP` which is not nullable and of data type `TIMESTAMP(6)`

Note: I do not need milliseconds only date & time should be fine

Comment: as if you missed to issue `connection.commit()` at the end ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two options here

Either you `commit` the transaction by using the corresponding method

```
  cursor.execute("INSERT INTO AB.CTIMEUPDATED(Tstamp) VALUES(TO_DATE(:TS, 'yyyy/mm/dd hh24:mi:ss'))", {'TS': dtime})
    connection.commit()
```

Or you use `autocommit` set to ON

```
 connection.autocommit = True 
     cursor.execute("INSERT INTO AB.CTIMEUPDATED(Tstamp) VALUES(TO_DATE(:TS, 'yyyy/mm/dd hh24:mi:ss'))", {'TS': dtime})
```